# Can get the actionBar reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

This is the code for my activity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the getActionBar() is red lined (Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.ActionBar to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar) but if you see the imports it is intended to be of support library. 
Well I just want to have a an actionbar reference as I am working with swiping tabs and which belong to support library. 
I mean can I get a reference to the actionBar for support library as I can have for non-support i.e. `ActionBar ab = getActionBar();` ?

Comment: use ActionBarActivity instead of using FragmentActivity.

Comment: won't that affect the fragments?

Comment: use AcionBar actionbar =getSupportActionBar(); ActionBarActivity already extends FragmentActivity

Comment: Extend Activity classes from ActionBarCompat: ActionBarCompat contains one Activity class which all of your Activity classes should extend: ActionBarActivity. This class itself extends from FragmentActivity so you can continue to use Fragments in your application. There is not a ActionBarCompat Fragment class that you need to extend, so you should continue using android.support.v4.Fragment as the base class for your Fragments. check these http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: Ok thanks. @Dhawal Sodha Parmar